# ACPI BIOS error and STONEY not supported in kfd on laptop

Tags: boot, acpi, amd, void-linux, runit

Please see the image before add answer.

[image: errors when booting]

```
[   2.2157971 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^*PB2.UGA.AFN?]
,AE_NOT_FOUND (28208528/psargs-330)
[   2.215823) ACPI Error:
AE_NOT_FOUND (28208528/psargs-330)
[   2.218328] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20288528/video-357)
[   2.4345621 kfd kfd: STONEY not supported in kfd
```

My laptop spec :

- Asus X555BP - BX921T,
- AMD A9-9420,
- Radeon R5 Graphics + R5 M420 (dual graphics),
- RAM = 4GB,
- storage = 1TB HDD,
- Distro = VoidLinux,
- DE = XFCE 4.14,
- Kernel = 5.8.18_1

I have tried updating the bios, but it turns out that my bios is up to date -> There is a pop up "build date is too old" when updating the BIOS. I've also installed `mesa-vulkan-radeon` as my GPU driver but still doesn't solve this problem.  According to https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/firmware.html, AMD Microcode is bundled with linux-firmware-amd which is already bundled with xorg as well.